# How to set the property `folderColorRgb` for all users?

Tags: google-drive-api

Good day, folks!

I am creating folders using API v3 `files/create` https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create.

I execute two similar requests with body:

```
{
  "folderColorRgb": "#AC725E",
  "description": "Folder description",
  "name": "MyColorfulFolder",
  "parents": [
    "<my parent id>"
  ],
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

The only major difference (except folder name being unique, of course) that the first request is coming from a service account, while another one from my personal account.

It seems that the folder color is set only for the account that invoked the request thus the other accounts don't see the color.

I am wondering, if there's a way to enforce the folder color-coding for all users?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Google documentation, all changes or customization you make to the folder colors are only to your view:

> You can customize the color of folders and shortcuts to folders in your My Drive and shared drives. If you change any colors, it only applies to your view in Drive.

Therefore, enforcing a color code in folders doesn't seem possible at the time.

The only way this seems almost feasible is if you have Google Workspace subscription and use a service account for 'user impersonation', then impersonate each user in the organization and apply the same color to your target folder(s).

#### References

[Change color of your foder- Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375091#zippy=%2Cchange-the-color-of-your-folder)

[User impersonation using a service account - Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#java)

Comment: Appreciate your help! Thank you!